# CSS Pausing an animation before it changes direction

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain to me how to pause an animation before it changes the direction? I'd like it to be blue for at least a minute and then start the transition to green again and keep green for a minute and so on...

```css
@keyframes BackgroundColorChange1 {
 from{background-color: #87D61D}
 to{background-color:#7091BE}
}

 body {
 background-color:#87D61D;
 animation-name: BackgroundColorChange1;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something [like this ?](https://jsfiddle.net/j9hkvte4/1/)

You can use percent instead of `from` `to` to control the animation better.

```
@keyframes BackgroundColorChange1 {
    0%{background-color: #87D61D}
    50%{background-color:#7091BE}
    100%{background-color:#87D61D}
}
```

Comment: This does the same thing. I want it to pause on #7091BE for at least a minute before it changes back to #87D61D and pauses again for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add steps in your animation: 
example with 2 extra steps

```css
@keyframes BackgroundColorChange1 {
 from{background-color: #87D61D}
 25%{background-color: #87D61D}
 75%{background-color:#7091BE}
 to{background-color:#7091BE}
}

 body {
 background-color:#87D61D;
 animation-name: BackgroundColorChange1;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```